# Why doesn't the position work properly in the section

Tags: html, css

I have a section part on the website where I want four products being displayed in the middle, right and left arrows on both sides of the screen and a title in the middle above the displayed products, I think I have all of the HTML and CSS good but the position isn't working properly, can someone have a look and help me feature it out?[img of the sections I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/af0vh.png)

ps: the background color doesn't feel the space that the items and buttons are in, why does it happens too?

edit: [this is a pic of how i wish it would look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdhCX.jpg)

**HTML**:

```
<section class="one">
        <div><span class="title">New products</span></div>
        <br>
        <button class="left">
            <span class="Lmain"></span>
            <span class="Lside"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="items">
            <div class="item">
                <a href="">
                    <img class="itemImg" src="../Images/Image1.png" alt="Picture of the product">
                </a>
                <div><span class="desc">Description about that specific item that is being showen to you above this text
                        right here</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="">
                    <img class="itemImg" src="../Images/Image2.png" alt="Picture of the product">
                </a>
                <div><span class="desc">Description about that specific item that is being showen to you above this text
                        right here</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="">
                    <img class="itemImg" src="../Images/Image3.png" alt="Picture of the product">
                </a>
                <div><span class="desc">Description about that specific item that is being showen to you above this text
                        right here</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="">
                    <img class="itemImg" src="../Images/Image4.png" alt="Picture of the product">
                </a>
                <div><span class="desc">Description about that specific item that is being showen to you above this text
                        right here</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="right">
            <span class="Rmain"></span>
            <span class="Rside"></span>
        </button>
    </section>
```

**CSS**:

```
.title {
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        margin: auto;
        border: 1px solid goldenrod;
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    .one {
        background-color: hotpink;
        position: relative;
    }

    .two {
        background-color: rgb(255, 0, 128);
    }

    /*items appearance*/
    .items {
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .item {
        border: 1px solid rgb(255, 170, 0);
        float: left;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        margin: 0px 8px;
        left: 12%;
        width: 350px;
        height: auto;
    }

    .itemImg {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    /*end of item appearance*/


    .right {
        right: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .left {
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you added an example of what you're trying to achieve, or better yet a running example :)

Comment: I have added, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1):

Utilize flexbox to make this layout easy:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h1#title {
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#products {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 0;
}

.product {
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  background: #fff;
  color: black;
  margin: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="title">Items</h1>
  <main>
    <div class="arrow" id="arrow-left">&#8592;</div>
    <div id="products">
      <div class="product">
        Product
      </div>
      <div class="product">
        Product
      </div>
      <div class="product">
        Product
      </div>
      <div class="product">
        Product
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow" id="arrow-right">&#8594;</div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: em.. I don't really know.. Anything... about flexbox... do you think there is a way to use position in this situation

Comment: I highly suggest watching a few tutorial videos on flexbox. It's really easy once you get the hang of the concepts and it's really powerful and fast.

Answer (score 0):

Here a list of problem I see:

- the `.title` element is `position:absolute`, so it doesn't *fill* any space and other elements will position weirdly. Solution: remove `position: absolute`
- the `.title` is a `<span>` element witch is an inline-element who doesn't behave like a block element (`<div>`, `<p>`, `<h1>`, etc.), so the `text-align: center` doesn't take effect. Solution: remove the span and give the `.title` class to the parent `<div>`
- the  left and right buttons should be wrapped in a `<div>` with `position:relative`

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andreacanton/mun128kg/4/) with the fixed code.

I didn't fix the image positioning because i think those will be positioned by js, anyhow it dipends by the images dimensions and is a very weak method. So I **strongly suggest** using *flexbox* that is [widely supported by browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

You can follow the [@yerme example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59775158/why-doesnt-the-position-work-properly-in-the-section/59775333#59775333) or [this guide on flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: Thank you, I will start to learn about it then, but do you think you can help me make the current code work with the positioning?

Comment: I've edited my answer with a jsfiddle with the code